# OSX Music Duration

Tags: macos, bash

I am trying to make a quick command that will delete all music files that have 0 seconds of music in them...

I have this:

```
afinfo * -r | grep "estimated duration: " | cut -c 21- | rev | cut -c 4- | rev
```

Which gives me the times but what do I change to make it scan my entire system and then delete ones that are 0 seconds?

Comment: you mean you need to collect all files which are supposed to be "music files"? use [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) utility with an appropriate search criteria to collect filenames and then apply your command to check if it's 0 seconds long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**

You *SHOULD* be able to use `mdfind` to do this, but I am not sure if it will work if your songs haven't been catalogued and indexed by OSX, but if it works for you it is easier than the longer answer below...

In theory, you can find all zero-duration songs below your HOME directory using:

```
mdfind -onlyin $HOME 'kMDItemDurationSeconds=0'
```

or something like:

```
mdfind -onlyin $HOME 'kMDItemDurationSeconds<0.01'
```

If that works and only lists songs you want deleted, you can string it together with `xargs` to remove the tracks like this:

```
mdfind -onlyin $HOME 'kMDItemDurationSeconds=0' | xargs -I % rm %
```

**Long Answer**

If you take this script and save it in a file called `DeleteZeroDuration`

```
#!/bin/bash
################################################################################
# DeleteZeroDuration
# Mark Setchell
# Delete songs with short duration
#
# Usage:
# DeleteZeroDuration song.mp3
################################################################################
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
   echo "Usage:"
   echo "$0 song.mp3|track.m4a"
   exit 1
fi
track="$1"
shorty=$(afinfo "$track" | awk 'BEGIN{short=0} /^estimated duration:/{if($3<0.1)short=1} END{print short}')
if [ $shorty -eq 1 ]; then
   echo "Would delete track: $track"
   # rm "$track"
fi
```

Then start Terminal and make the script executable, using:

```
chmod +x DeleteZeroDuration
```

You can try it out on a song or two with

```
./DeleteZeroDuration SomeSong.mp3
```

and it will tell you if it would delete the track, or do nothing if it would not. It will not actually delete anything because the `rm` in the penultimate line is commented out.

When you are happy it works, you can run it on all the songs in your HOME directory using:

```
find $HOME -iname "*.mp3" -exec ./DeleteZeroDuration {} \;
```

or

```
find $HOME -iname "*.m4a" -exec ./DeleteZeroDuration {} \;
```

If that seems like it is good, go ahead and remove the `#` in front of `rm "$track"` so that it actually does the deletion.

Be careful and run it on a dummy copy of your actual music library first.